# 8.1 Universal App. Getting user input from the Grid or Page (KeyDown event)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm quite new to using XAML and was wondering if it is possible to get the users keyboard input directly from the Grid or the Page by grabbing a character at a time?

I've been trying using the KeyDown event which I put on both the grid and the page but the only way either seems to fire is if enter is pressed or if it is tabbed over.

I was wondering if I possibley need to set focus on them to capture the input?

```
<Page
x:Class="Test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" KeyDown="Page_KeyDown" Loaded="Page_Loaded"
>

<Grid  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown">

</Grid>
```

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks